# How do I refactor common map for Single/Observable inside of if block

Tags: java, rx-java

How can I refactor this piece of code? If I move `.map()` out of `flatMapSingle` I'll lose `id`.

```
Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
          .flatMapSingle(id -> {
              if (id % 2 == 0)
              {
                  return loadObjectSingle(id)
                        .map(object -> Entry(id, object));
              }
              else
              {
                  return loadFakeObjectSingle(id)
                          .map(object -> Entry(id, object));
              }
          })
```

Comment: Refactor it to do what? (I guess the `;` after `loadObjectSingle` is a typo)

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, I don't really like 2 identical maps (and the fact that they're nested is bad).

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the single so you only do the map once.

```
Observable
  .fromArray(1, 2, 3)
  .flatMapSingle(id -> {
     Single<T> single;
     if (id % 2 == 0) {
        single = loadObjectSingle(id);
     } else {
        single = loadFakeObjectSingle(id);
     }
     return single.map(object -> Entry(id, object));
   });
```